# How to call a function from view holder inside fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Inside my `ViewHolder` I have implementation of edit mode(click on text become editText) but when I'm exiting the app without confirm editing and come back the edit mode is still on(It doesn't happen if I navigate to different screen by the way).

How can I call a function from  the ViewHolder inside onPause method in order to cancel the edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ViewHolder set an onFocusChangeListener for your EditText, when focus is lost make it back to TextView.

Comment: Nice idea, unfortunately it doesn't detect home button press

Comment: Assuming that there is only one edit text at the time: inside your adapter save the position of the item when you change the text view in editText, then in the onPause method get the viewholder associated with the position with :  
 myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(adapter.pos)                                                                                   then do your thing with the views inside the holder.  Note: if the item is not visible it will give null